# Disable button on mouse (Logitech M720 Triathlon)

Tags: debian, xorg, mouse, xinput

There's a button on my mouse that I'm unable to disable. It's right next to my thumb and I keep clicking it by accident. It triggers some kind of alt+tab function and it's very annoying!

Here is my xinput output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M720 Triathlon                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger touch  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan TrackPoint                           id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser    id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple, Inc Apple Keyboard                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple, Inc Apple Keyboard                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech M720 Triathlon                   id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Here is the `xinput test 11` output, when I click the button:

```
key press   37 
key press   64 
key press   23 
key release 23 
key release 64 
key release 37
```

edit: xev output

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x16b, subw 0x0, time 3927972, (-192,136), root:(679,596),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x16b, subw 0x0, time 3927980, (-192,136), root:(679,596),
    state 0x14, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x16b, subw 0x0, time 3927988, (-192,136), root:(679,596),
    state 0x1c, keycode 23 (keysym 0xff09, Tab), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) "   "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Is there a way to ignore device ID 11 on startup? If so, how, and how do I make sure it doesn't ignore something else on boot up? I could just ignore these keypresses in xinput but then my keyboard won't be able to press these anymore.

Comment: `It triggers some kind of alt+tab function` ... first, determine exactly what function is triggered ... then search for the hotkey preset for that function and change it

Comment: @jsotola I edited my question. At the third line of each paragraph in the xev output, you can see it triggers the following keys: Control_L, Alt_L and Tab.

Comment: Nice first question, well written!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mouse presents itself both as a mouse and a keyboard. You can disable the keyboard part with:

```
$ xinput disable 19
```

Usually you would use the name of the device "Logitech M720 Triathlon" as the last parameter, but the mouse gets the same name, so you'll have to get the number from processing the list. Something like:

```
$ xinput disable $(xinput --list | grep M720.*keyboard | sed -E 's/.*id=([0-9]+).*/\1/g')
```

To set it up at the beginning of the Xfce session you can check [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xfce#Autostart).

Comment: It changes on reboot. This is what I feared! When I disconnect, reboot, and reconnect, the ID is different. The ids are now 19 and 20.

Comment: Also, I don't see why I would ask another question. My original questions explicitly aims to answer this.

Comment: Because it is another issue. It has nothing to do with the button. You can ask many things at once, but that doesn't make it right. In this case, running somehing at boot might depend on wether you are using xfce4 (just add a start up script), gnome, kde, plain X (and you'd go for .xinitrc) ... It might look like part of the same problem, but it is unrelated, and kind of unanswerable with the system information you've provided so far and most likely already answered in another question.

Comment: oh i see. I'm using XFCE. I just added the command in my init script trough the GUI.

Comment: Then, with the new command, that searches for the right device, and your init script, you should be all set. In case the answer is useful you should upvote it, if it actually solves your issue, accept it, so that other people with the same problem can get there right away.

Comment: please edit your answer to include that that command should be included in the ~/.bashrc file. It's the only place that works. Going trough the GUI and adding it on XFCE will not work!

Comment: In XFCE I have some programs with autostart and some in .xinitrc and both systems work. You have to be sure the scripts have the right permissions and it's best to run the commands with full paths. Adding it to .bashrc is not a good idea because you'll be running the program every time you open a new terminal/bash shell. Try `.xinitrc` and, if it does not work, you can always ask. By the way, if it doesn't work, `.~/xsession-errors` might have more information.

Answer (score 0):

To map the thumb button on the Logitech M720 Triathlon Multi-Device Mouse open dconf editor and navigate to org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/wm/(switch-panels),
turn off Use Default Value. Enter into Custom value what you will. Since I wanted to *disable* the thumb button I entered [''], essentially a null value. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS if that adds anything to my answer.

Comment: Well, I clearly don't know what I'm talking about because when I rebooted and the problem reappeared I checked dconf and was told to reload my instruction, viz, [''] is not an acceptable value even though it did work previously. A long time ago I could program a bit, now I know nothing.

Comment: What I have discovered is that the default value, Control-Alt-Tab, causes the mouse wheel to focus on the zoom level in Firefox, and it also highlights any tabs that are opened

Answer (score 0):

Searching some more I did find an answer, sort of. There is a linux software called **Piper** (https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/11/configure-logitech-steelseries-and.html) and I was able to map the 'Unknown' key to going Forward in Firefox, and since I rarely have the opportunity to move a page forward the button effectively does nothing. In Piper there are many functions to which the buttons can be mapped.